# Pandas groupby: straight-forward counting the number of elements in each group is very slow

Tags: python, count, group-by, pandas

I need some statistics of a binned data.
I thought the `pandas` `groupby` method would be a very natural approach.

Trying to improve performance, I realised that dropping the `count` method from the list passed to `agg` improves significantly.

To my surprise, extracting the count from the ratio of sum/mean gives a significant improvement.
In my real-world application this results in over **100 times** improvement in the calculation time.

I wonder whether I am misusing the code somehow.

In the following you can find an artificial example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.randn(5000), ## produce the demo DataFrame 
   ...:                    'y':np.random.randn(5000),
   ...:                    'z':np.random.randn(5000)})

In [4]: buckets = {col : np.arange(int(df[col].min()) ,int(df[col].max())+2) 
   ...:            for col in df.columns} ## produce the unit bins

In [5]: cats = [pd.cut(df[col], bucket) for col,bucket in buckets.iteritems()]

In [6]: grouped = df.groupby(cats) # group by the binned x,y,z

In [7]: %%timeit
   ...: fast_count = grouped.x.agg(['sum','mean','var'])
   ...: fast_count = (fast_count['sum']/fast_count['mean'] + 0.5).astype(np.int)   ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.06 ms per loop

In [8]: %%timeit
   ...: slow_count = grouped.x.count()
   ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 18.9 ms per loop

In [9]: fast_count = grouped.x.agg(['sum','mean','var'])

In [10]: fast_count = (fast_count['sum']/fast_count['mean'] + 0.5).astype(np.int)

In [11]: slow_count = grouped.x.count()

In [12]: (fast_count != slow_count).sum()
Out[12]: 0

In [13]: (fast_count == slow_count).sum()
Out[13]: 204
```

#### Thanks to Jeff's reply (below), a more elegant code (showing comparable performance):

```
In [17]: %%timeit
   ....: another_fast_count = grouped.x.size()
   ....: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 609 µs per loop
```

see the comments following Jeff's reply for some explanations

#### NB (based on [hayd's comment](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6312#issuecomment-36664683) ):

`count` counts only non-null elements while `size` will not differentiate.
This is probably the reason for the difference in performance.
Therefore the choice between the two options should be taken with care.

Answer (score 4):

Try using `.size`. `count` is going into python space to do an actual calculation; whereas `size` is using pre-computed group data. It prob a nice PR to implement `count` in terms of size (to avoid this confusion).

```
In [8]: %timeit grouped.x.size()
1000 loops, best of 3: 500 ﾵs per loop

In [9]: %timeit grouped.x.count()
100 loops, best of 3: 19.4 ms per loop

In [10]: grouped.x.size().equals(grouped.x.count())
Out[10]: True
```

Comment: `size` is much more elegant than my solution (hence the **+1**); thanx! Still - one cannot pass it, as with `count` (and `mean`, `sum`,...), in a list of functions to `agg`. Any idea what is the advantage in the way `count` is implemented right now?

Comment: ``count`` is delegating to the underlying frame. some functions like ``mean``,``sum`` are implemented in cython so very fast. ``size`` actually is a special one in that once you groupby it is already done. i'll create an issue to address this; essentially need to have count call size; prob a bug that it can't be used in an aggregator.

Comment: Thanx for both the explanation and opening the github issue!